# How to change selected material bottom tab's splash color?

Tags: react-native

I just start react native.

How do I change the pink splash colour on the home tab?

[image: 1]

The screenshot is from an android 12 device, but I tried it on an older android version and there isn't that splash pink colour but instead the standard android ripple effect.

**app.tsx**

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

import Settings from './screens/settings';
import Home from './screens/home';
import Search from './screens/search';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

import {
    StyleSheet,
    SafeAreaView,
} from "react-native";
import React from 'react';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.background}>
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Tab.Navigator
                    initialRouteName="Home"
                    shifting={true}
                    barStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'rgb(220, 220, 220)' }}
                    activeColor="black"
                    compact={false}
                    sceneAnimationEnabled={true}
                    inactiveColor='grey'
                >

                    <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }) => (
                            <Icon type='ionicon' name={focused ? 'settings' : "settings-outline"} color={color}></Icon>
                        ),
                    }} />
                    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }) => (
                            <Icon type='ionicon' name={focused ? 'home' : "home-outline"} color={color}></Icon>
                        ),
                    }} />
                    <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={Search} options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }) => (
                            <Icon type='ionicon' name={focused ? 'search' : "search-outline"} color={color}></Icon>
                        ),
                    }} />

                </Tab.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
            <StatusBar backgroundColor={'#fff'} barStyle={'dark-content'}></StatusBar>
        </SafeAreaView >
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background: {
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        flex: 1.0
    },
});
```

**settings.tsx**

```js
function Settings() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.background}>


        </SafeAreaView >
    );
}
```

**home.tsx**

```js
function Home() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.background}>

        </SafeAreaView >
    );
}
```

**search.tsx**

```js
function Search() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.background}>

        </SafeAreaView >
    );
}
```

I erased some non relevant parts in the home, settings and search pages, for clearness.

I tried any settings that i could think of, but i didn't find any that would change that ugly pink color.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `tabBarColor​` in the options of `Tab.Screen`? Or `screenOptions` prop with `tabBarActiveBackgroundColor​` from `Tab.Navigator`?

Comment: yes i tried them both, tabBarColor changes the color of the tab bar with another splash effect, but it doesn't changer that pink color. For tabBarActiveBackgroundColor, vscode gives me an error if i specify it this way in Tab.Navigator:
screenOptions={
    { tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: "red", }
   }
If i run it with expo, it doesn't give any error but there is no visible effect.